# Scroll my view to show All editText when the keyboard is opened

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have four Text views under each other inside scroll view
and I start my activity with keyboard opened 
I want to make my scroll view scroll to show me the lowest text view in my layout 
so I can see All the text Views , how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the fullScroll function:

```
scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

if you need focus on a specific view try this:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
v.setFocusable(true);
v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
v.requestFocus();
```

Comment: but this method scroll to the bottom of my scroll and I want to scroll to lowest text view only I mean there is other controls under the text views that I contain in my layout